# Panel Data for 20 countries with same independent variable for each country

Tags: regression, econometrics, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I am analyzing the impact of US monetary policy variables on capital flows to emerging markets and intend to use panel data analysis. I have data on capital flows for 20 countries individually from 2000-2018 and US monetary policy variables for the same period.

What I don't understand is that the US monetary policy variables (inflation, industrial production, spead) - the independent variables would remain the same for every country from 2000-2018.

Is it correct to use panel regression in this case?

Comment: This is a mix of economics and statistics. For me, lack of understanding of the econ also clouds the statistical issues. 20 countries. How many variables? Each variable separately of some sort of overall score. // Are you stating that--or wondering whether--US policy variable are constant? How does that relate to the 20 countries and however many variables?

Comment: For each country I have data on capital outflows and inflows (that would be the two dependent variables and would be analyzed seperately). The independent variables are US inflation, production and federal funds rate. So no matter what the US variables over the period 2000-2018 would be same for every country (repeated observations). That is, these variables does not vary across countries.